# How do Kramnik and Topalov indicate a resignation when they play together?

Tags: resigning, kramnik, topalov

From [What is the correct resignation procedure?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/4427/what-is-the-correct-resignation-procedure) it is clear that, although FIDE has no special rules governing on *how* you resign, it is common to either offer your hand or make some sort of exclamation (i.e. "I resign!"). What is important is that your intention to resign is unambiguous.

Now, the rivalry between Kramnik and Topalov has gone to such an extend that each player refuses to shake the other's hand or engage in any kind of pleasantries. Which raises the question - how do they go about resigning when playing each other without creating confusion about their intention?

Comment: You can also resign by stopping your clock

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If I remember correctly, they either just sign the scoresheet or stop the clock first and then sign the scoresheet to indicate that they resigned. There is no handshake, and they do not speak to each other since the [WCC2006 controversy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Chess_Championship_2006#Bathroom_controversy).

Here are two examples:
[Candidates Tournament 2014, Rd. 13](https://youtu.be/Ab2trGXekwc?t=4h57m48s) (Kramnik-Topalov 1-0),
[Norway Chess 2014, Rd. 6](https://youtu.be/DWsQT2iovY0?t=57m22s) (Topalov-Kramnik 1-0).

**Addendum.** Not asked in the original post, but one interesting (and related) question is also: How do Kramnik and Topalov agree to a draw? Signing the scoresheet or stopping the clock is not appropriate in this case, since the opponent might want to continue playing.

One obvious way is to repeat the position three times. If there is no threefold repetition on the horizon, the players can offer a draw through the arbiter (like in Sofia rules, used, for example, during the [WCC 2010](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Chess_Championship_2010#Match_conditions)).

Answer (score -3):

Knocking over your king has always been a perfectly acceptable way of resigning.

With the king being the tallest piece on the board it can often happen that somebody wearing a long sleeved shirt can accidentally knock over their king when moving a piece near the king. I often, as a joke, hold out my hand before they've had a chance to pick the king up as if accepting their resignation. If they look puzzled rather than amused I point to their horizontal king. Hopefully at that stage they'll smile.

Comment: [Question is about Kramnik Topalov how come there's an answer in general?](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/question-is-about-kramnik-topalov-how-come-theres-an-answer-in-general)